# Fill byte array with mixed types at specific areas

Tags: java, arrays, types, byte, mixed

I want to fill a byte array with the following structure.
[Character][Number]@@[String]

So the character needs 1 byte. The Number needs 2 bytes for numbers with two digits. Then there comes two @ and then a string.

My problem is that the second information, the number, is either one digit or two.
I create a byte array with the following size: `message.getBytes().length+5`.

What i want is that i can fill this array with the informations and knowing that the message always starts at the 5 position.

I started with something like this:

```
byteArray[0] = 'm';
byteArray[1] = number;
byteArray[2] = number;
//here comes the problem. How should I check whenever its 1 or 2 digit integer and how do I save it?
```

The integer number should always take 2 bytes to save so I know where the real message starts.

Comment: A character is _two bytes_ in Java

Comment: You never told us how you are getting user input and additionally what do you want to happen when the user enters the wrong input?

Comment: Do you want a string output or a byte array? That is quite not the same thing; in the first case you'll need a `char[]`, not a `byte[]`.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Why do you want to use a byte array? I'm not sure using a byte array is the best way to go, but I can't tell yet.